# Sending Txt file to server from client using python sockets

Tags: python, file

i am trying to create a server/client in python using sockets for sending text and other media files.
**Scenario:-** Client takes host, port and file name as parameters and send the file to server.
**Error Description:-** while trying to execute the below client code, having text file "tos" in same directory as client.Getting below error.

```
**$ python Cli.py 127.0.0.1 5007 tos**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Cli.py", line 32, in <module>
    client= Client(host,port,file)
  File "Cli.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.connect(file)
  File "Cli.py", line 20, in connect
    self.sendFile(file)
  File "Cli.py", line 26, in sendFile
    readByte = open(file, "rb")
**IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''**
```

Note:- Also please describe if there is anyway to send file to server, searching the hard drive.

**Server:-**

```
from socket import *
port = 5007
file = ''
class Server:
    gate = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)   
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port
        self.gate.bind((self.host, self.port))  
        self.listen()

    def listen(self):
        self.gate.listen(10)
        while True:
            print("Listening for connections, on PORT: ", self.port)
            add = self.gate.accept()
            self.reciveFileName()
            self.reciveFile()


    def reciveFileName(self):
        while True:
            data = self.gate.recv(1024)
            self.file = data

    def reciveFile(self):
        createFile = open("new_"+self.file, "wb")
        while True:
            data = self.gate.recv(1024)
            createFile.write(data)
        createFile.close()
server= Server(port)
listen()
```

**Client:-**

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
from socket import *
host = ''
port = 5007
file = ''
class Client:
    gateway = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    def __init__(self, host,port, file):
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.file = file
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        self.gateway.connect((self.host, self.port))
        self.sendFileName(file)
        self.sendFile(file)

    def sendFileName(self):
        self.gateway.send("name:" +self.file)

    def sendFile(self):
        readByte = open(self.file, "rb")
        data = readByte.read()
        readByte.close()

        self.gateway.send(data)
        self.gateway.close()
client= Client(host,port,file)
connect()
```

Comment: Did you ever intend on giving the file a name?

Comment: the scenario is i do not want to hardcode the filename. instead want the client program to find the file on giving it through command line and send it.

Comment: Yeah... but you're not doing that...

Comment: right now, i have put the file to send in the same directory as of client program. Please advise if i have to give some more parameters for program to find my file.

Comment: can you please provide some guideline as what module should i use for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment `file = ''` which in not a valid filename.  I would also suggest renaming `file` to `filename` for clarity.

Comment: Hi Steve, modified file as filename. Still same error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Cli.py", line 29, in <module>
    client= Client(host,port,filename)
  File "Cli.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "Cli.py", line 17, in connect
    self.sendFile()
  File "Cli.py", line 23, in sendFile
    readByte = open(self.filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: But you are still not proving any CONTENT for filename - i.e. self.filename = './Fred.txt' should result in either Fred.txt from the current directory being sent or and error messages saying "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Fred.txt'"

Comment: The other options would be to supply the file name to as a command line argument or prompt the user for it - take a look at the documents for sys.argv and rawinput as starting points.

Answer (score 0):

Had this task as Homework 3 months ago.
The solution for this is pretty simple - You simply need to read the file, put the readed text in a string variable and send it. Look at this server code:

```
HOST = '192.168.1.100'
PORT = 8012
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serversock.bind(ADDR)
serversock.listen(SOMAXCONN)

fileOpen = open("D:/fileLocation.txt")
g = f.read()
print 'Waiting For Connection..'
clientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
print 'Connection Established From: ', addr`
clientsock.sendall(g)
```

This is a very **simple** way to do so.

The client simply receives the data (as text) and save it in the wanted location.

Worked for me with BMP,PNG and JPG images also.

Comment: Hi C0LDSH3LL,
thanks for the reply. But in fact my query is little bit diff. I need my client program to look for the file on my hard drive, find it and then send it to server.
as input i have to give host port and file name to the client program.

Comment: Ok, so simply ask for the file name, and search it using a simple for loop in C:/ or D:/.
Basicly this would be a weird thing to do, because you can ask the user to simply choose the file location